# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource when i am using a public URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to call sample service using Ajax. Below is the code i am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date1;
    var time1;
    var time2;
    var date2
    function CallService() {
        date1 = new Date();
        time1 = date1.getMilliseconds();
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.google.co.in",
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });

        return false;
    }

    function OnSuccess(data, status) {
        alert('success');
    }

    function OnError(request, status, error) {
        alert('error');
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
    });
</script>
```

I know that if we add **header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');** in server will remove the issue.

But i don't have access to the server side code so please can some one tell me how can i enable cross domain access in javascript.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try to `change contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",`  to `contentType: "text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"",`

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header exists for a reason, it allows server to restrict who can make cross domain requested to its resources. If there is any work around, then it is a bug. So, you wont be able to make ajax requests if server doesn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSONP` which stands for `“JSON with Padding”` and it is a workaround for loading data from different domains. It loads the script into the head of the DOM and thus you can access the information as if it were loaded on your own domain, thus by-passing the cross domain issue

Basic Example : http://jsfiddle.net/yvzSL/714/

Please refer "http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/" for more examples